# Whats difference between models.py & forms.py?

Tags: python, django

I am learning about Django & Python from past two weeks.though,  my reading i came across models.py & forms.py. structure of both this is almost same. can anyone explain me whats the difference between them?

I also want to know where do i have to write the `(<form> </form>)` code. I mean in any html file or *.py  file or where?

Comment: Please, read the Django tutorial: https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: yes. I am learning mostly form there only, but still not getting the proper explanation

Comment: What would you consider to be a *"proper explanation"*? What makes you think that the community here is more capable of enlightening you than whoever produced the documentation? Could you provide particular quotes from the documentation that confuse you, and explain precisely what it is you aren't getting?

Answer (score 4):

They are indeed very different in concept, albeit they can look similar. Let me explain:

**Models** define your business objects and data structures. They are the "entities" of the application wich have to be persisted in the database. Since it's a definition of the objects and their attributes, you define "fields". They represent the data structure and persistence of the app.

**Forms** are meant to make easier to get input from the user, validate data, render html and recover values supplied by the user. They also have fields but you have to note they don't map to a database and they don't represent an entity. They represent the "inputs" of the app.